# String formatting is not working in mail sending

Tags: java, spring, string, email

My string is like below

```
String content  = 
"Dear user,

    <font face="Arial">Hello</font>

Regards,
Gen";
```

I am passing this `content` to the mail sender.

```
    `MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    String encodingOptions = "text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed";
    try{
        message.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "utf-8");
        boolean isHTML = true;
        helper.setFrom(mailFrom);
        helper.setTo(to.replaceAll("\\s",""));
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setText(content, isHTML);`
```

And this `content` String I am passing to the mail send like above, and it is in the format of `html`. When I recieve the mail I am getting the mail like below

`Dear user,Hello Regards,Gen`

How can I display the `content` in the below format.

```
Dear user,

    Hello

Regards,
Gen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's HTML you have to add the line breaks yourself. I am not a frontend developer but you can use `<p>` tag or `<br/>`.
Try something like:

```
String content  = 
"Dear user, <br/>

   <p> <font face="Arial">Hello</font></p>

Regards, <br/>
Gen";
```

Answer (score 3):

The message is exactly what you've created. In short HTML doesn't care about spaces and newlines. You can test your HTML online to see how it looks, ie. here:
https://htmledit.squarefree.com/

For your message to be properly formatted, try something between the lines of:

```
<html>
<span>Dear user,</span></br></br>
<span><font face="Arial">Hello</font><span></br></br>

<span>Regards,</span></br>
<span>Gen</span>
</html>
```

You need to provide breaklines yourself. You could probably omit `<span>` tags.